# regEx to find a dynamic substring in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string which contains a markup. Inside the markup there is an identifier/or substring which I want to pick which would look like this

```
ghost://{schema_name}/{id}
```

as an example

```
 ghost://blogging/232323
```

Note: if required, we can change the identifier to something we can find more easily in our string.

Consider this as a string

```
const somesting = `
<h1> Random Heading </h1> 
<p> Random Text </p> 
<p> a href="ghost://blogging/232323"> Text I want to pick </a> </p>
`
```

Here, I want to pick `ghost://blogging/232323` and change it to an actual link.

From googling, I found that I can achieve this by using grammar but I am not sure how to write grammar/regular expression here (or any other way)

Would so appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Based on the answer by CertainPerformance, I did this but unfortunately this isn't working

```js
const somesting = `
<h1> Random Heading </h1> 
<p> Random Text </p> 
<p> a href="ghost://xman-article/HPHvLTH06YUMfdMnokOl/spaceyfi-product-launch"> Text I want to pick </a> </p>
`;

const replaced = somesting.replace(
  /ghost:\/\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/g,
  (_, schema_name, id, slug) => `/${schema_name}/${id}/${slug}`
);

console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: What do you mean by grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match `ghost://`, followed by word characters (or whatever characters are permitted for the schema name), followed by another slash and number. Here's an example of how you'd dynamically replace that with `a href="https://blogging.com/article/232323"`:

```js
const somesting = `
<h1> Random Heading </h1> 
<p> Random Text </p> 
<p> a href="ghost://blogging/232323"> Text I want to pick </a> </p>
`;

const replaced = somesting.replace(
  /ghost:\/\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/g,
  (_, schema_name, id) => `https://${schema_name}.com/article/${id}`
);
console.log(replaced);
```

The schema name and id are variables inside the `.replace` callback, so feel free to use them however you need to there, and return the string to be replaced at the end of the callback.

If you have a third part of the `ghost` that you need to capture, then make a third capturing group so that the fourth parameter to the `.replace` callback can see it:

```js
const somesting = `
<h1> Random Heading </h1> 
<p> Random Text </p> 
<p> a href="ghost://xman-article/HPHvLTH06YUMfdMnokOl/spaceyfi-product-launch"> Text I want to pick </a> </p>
`;

const replaced = somesting.replace(
  /ghost:\/\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^"])/g,
  (_, schema_name, id, slug) => `/${schema_name}/${id}/${slug}`
);

console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, update the snippet which I tried and isn't working

Comment: If you want to be able to use another parameter, you'll need to capture another group in the pattern. It's not clear, but you might not actually need to capture these - if you just need the whole string past the `ghost`, but not the individual elements of it, you can just use *one* capture group around everything after `ghost` instead.